# Changing boolean with link_to Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is what it said in my local server:

```
Started GET "/hunt/one" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-04-14 23:54:47 -0700
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by HuntController#one as HTML
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered hunt/one.html.erb (281.8ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 406ms

ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"update_clue1", :controller=>"clue", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]):
```

In my controller

```
def update_clue1
@clue = Clue.find(1)
@clue.update_attributes(clue1: true)
redirect_to "/home/clues"
end
```

In my routes

```
resources :clue do
  member do
       get :update_clue1
       put :update_clue1
    end
end
```

In my view

```
<%= link_to "See next clue", update_clue1_clue_path(@clue), method: :put, class: "btn btn-default" %>
```

Thanks for the help!

EDIT

```
New Error  /Users/coleschiffer/Code/rp/protected-beyond-7706/app/controllers/hunt_controller.rb:14: class/module name must be CONSTANT
```

Here is the hunt controller

```
def update_clue1   
   @clue = Clue.find(1)     
   @clue.update_attributes(clue1: true)     
   redirect_to "/home/clues     "
end
```

Comment: Set `@clue` instance variable in the action from which you're rendering your link.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Do you mean add clue to routes.rb? I did that.

Comment: No, I mean put `@clue = ...` in `hunt_controller#one` action.

Comment: Thanks, what would I set it to? I thought it was already defined.

Comment: I guess you know better than I which `Clue` record you want to pass into the link.

Comment: Isn't the clue controller doing that?

Comment: No, you want to generate your link in `hunt_controller` action, right? Did you go through any Rails guide/tutorial before?

Comment: The only reason was that at one point this worked and I remembered it being in the clues controller, Anyways the same error is popping up after I move it to the Hunt controller.

Comment: Show your `hunt_controller` and most recent error.

Comment: Heres the error  `/Users/coleschiffer/Code/rp/protected-beyond-7706/app/controllers/hunt_controller.rb:14: class/module name must be CONSTANT`  and here is the hunt controller `def update_clue1   
@clue = Clue.find(1)     
@clue.update_attributes(clue1: true)     
redirect_to "/home/clues     "
end
class clues
  def set(string)
    var_name = "@clue"  # the '@' is required
    self.instance_variable_set(var_name, '@clue')
  end    
end`

Comment: Could you paste this information in question?

Comment: Also, please add note which line is 14th in `hunt_controller`.

Comment: Ok, your whole `class clues` definition doesn't make any sense. Remove it.

Comment: Okay thanks for all of the help, now it's back to the old error `No route matches {:action=>"update_clue1", :controller=>"clue", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]`

Comment: Not only this, `update_clue1` in hunts controller also doesn't make any sense. I told you to move only `@clue = ...` to `hunts#one` action. I REALLY advice you to learn some basics about Ruby and Rails.

Comment: I appreciate your help, although the code may not be great at one point it worked with something very similar to what I have now. I also ran some of the commands from the update_clue1 in rails console and they worked.